# How to save a big image with jsPDF?

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I want to pdf a big image by jsPDF. My problem is doing it for big image. I want to keep image resolution. I have my image size in pixel but I can't set size to jsPDF. I do as follow:

```
var pdf = new jsPDF();
var imgData = 'data:image/png;base64,iV...';

pdf.setFontSize(40);
pdf.text(35, 25, "Octonyan loves jsPDF");
pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 15, 40, 180, 180);
pdf.save();
```

Run at [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zo2Lhdx5/).

The code create a pdf but don't protect image resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `new jsPDF('l', 'px', [pdfHeight, pdfWidth]);` first parameter (landscape or portrait) second one is the unit

this is the [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zo2Lhdx5/33/)

```js
var imgData = 'data:image/png;base64,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';
var button = document.createElement('button');
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = imgData;
img.onload = function(){
button.onclick = function(){
  var pdf = new jsPDF();
  var left = 15, top = 40;  
  
  var width = pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
  var maxWidth = (width - left*2);
  var newWidth = img.naturalWidth < maxWidth ? img.naturalWidth : maxWidth;
  var newHeight = img.naturalHeight*newWidth/img.naturalWidth;
  
  var left = 15, top = 40;
  var pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'px', [img.naturalHeight+top*2, img.naturalWidth+left*2]);  
  
  pdf.setFontSize(40);
  pdf.text(35, 25, "Octonyan loves jsPDF");
  pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', left, top, img.naturalWidth, img.naturalHeight);
  pdf.save();
};
button.innerText = 'Create PDF and Download It'
document.body.appendChild(button);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/dist/jspdf.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I want to print image in origin resolution, in the solution, it's not.

Comment: @MortezaMalvandi you are joking, you want to print an image that have the width of 2000px in a pdf page that have the width of 200px

Comment: Yes I want to create a pdf with 2000px